# Correct english word for undoing a knot: untangle, disentangle, untie?

Tags: single-word-requests, academia, academic-writing

What's the best English word to describe the undoing of a knot? Some I have in mind: untangle, disentangle, untie.

I would like to use this word as an adjective. Here is an example sentence:

> After undoing the knot, the string became **untangled**.

What's the best word to use here? Is it *untangle*, *disentangle*, or *untie*? Something else? I will use this in academic writing, so my question is what is the "most correct" choice, and the most immediately understandable.

UPDATE. Another possibility: [unknot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unknot)

Comment: When creating a knot, do you tangle it, entangle it or tie it?

Comment: What do you want to say about the string that "undoing the knot" doesn't already say? Sometimes when I untie a knot, I make a mistake and the string becomes 'entangled'. It also depends on what you mean by a 'knot'? Is it neatly tied or is it a tangle? If the latter, you don't so much untie the knot but untangle it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I want an adjective, see the example sentence. What word can I use in place of the one in bold? If "untangle" is correct, that's also fine (I just want to confirm it is correct)

Comment: @KillingTime Are you asking me? I'm not a native English speaker, so I'd like someone else opinion.

Comment: As I asked, is the knot in the string already a tangle, or is it a neat formal knot?

Comment: The point is that _undoing/untying_ a knot results in two straight pieces of string, so you don't need to refer to disentangling the string - _unless_ it was tangled _as well as_ tied in a knot.

Comment: The thing is that after untying the knot, the string doesn't _become_ anything, the _knot_ is now untied, but the string remains a string as it was before, so it is hard to think of a word that would fit. Can you give us more context? Is this a single piece of string with a knot? Is the knot connecting two pieces of string? Connecting the string to something else? Please clarify what property of the string you want to describe.

Comment: Here's [a string with a single knot](https://www.123rf.com/photo_81856072_string-of-red-rope-knot-isolated-on-white-background.html) I'd say **untie the knot** or **undid the knot** and here are some [tangled shoe laces](https://www.freeimages.co.uk/galleries/home/general/slides/abstractlaces.htm) **He untangled his laces** seems the best fit

Comment: "After undoing the knot“ sounds perfectly reasonable to my ears, you could add "the string was loose".

Comment: knots and tangles are two different realities.